# How to get value of a pressed button

Tags: android

Hi all I am new to android development, infact its my first application. I want to know

```
<button
 android:text="1" />
```

in above tag, text is the value of the button? if yes then how i can get this value or store it in a variable. if not, then how to define a value behind any button in android?

Comment: This is really basic functionality. Have you even looked at the API? Button's extend Textiviews ( http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html ).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

yes its a value of Button , use following code to fetch Text of Button.

```
Button b = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
String buttonText = b.getText().toString();
```

**function call**

```
b.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
                  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                  function();
    }
});
```

Comment: will this onClick() method be called automatically when clicked on a button?

Comment: i got it. i want the same thing but on click :(. How a function will be called when clicked on any button?

Comment: thanks for this. marked it as true but not have enough repute to vote up :)

Answer (score 4):

You first need to give the button an id, like so:

```
<Button 
android:id="@+id/buttonId"
android:text="1"
 />
```

And then in your code do something like:

```
Button b = (Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonId);
b.getText(); // returns the value of your text.
```

Answer (score 2):

```
<Button
  android:id="@+id/button1"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:text="ButtonText" />
```

...

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  Button btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
  String text = btn.getText().toString();

}
```